# how to display only certains xml element in a xsl stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml, xslt-1.0

I want to display only **institution content-type="original"** and **label** in my xhtml output, but my code does not work. I'm using [JATS preview stylesheet](https://github.com/ncbi/JATSPreviewStylesheets/).

Here is a part of my xml

```
<aff id="aff3">
    <label>3</label>
    <institution content-type="original"> Tecnológico de Monterrey, Monterrey, México, email: email@mail.mx</institution>
    <institution content-type="normalized">Tecnológico de Monterrey</institution>
    <institution content-type="orgname">Tecnológico de Monterrey</institution>
    <addr-line>
        <named-content content-type="city">Monterrey</named-content>
    </addr-line>
    <country country="MX">Mexico</country>
    <email>mail@mail.mx</email>
</aff>
```

and here is a part of my xsl

```
<div id="aff-autor">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="metadata" select="aff"/>
    <!--xsl:value-of select="content-type[.='original']"/ -->
    <xsl:if test="content-type[.='original']"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="content-type[.='original']"/>
</div>
```

and here is my result

```
<p class="metadata-entry">
    <a id="aff3">
        <!-- named anchor -->
    </a>
    <span class="generated">[</span>3<span class="generated">] </span>
                 Tecnológico de Monterrey, Monterrey, México, email: katherina.gallardo@itesm.mx
                Tecnológico de Monterrey
                Tecnológico de Monterrey

    <span class="city">Monterrey</span>
                Mexico
    <a href="mailto:katherina.gallardo@itesm.mx">katherina.gallardo@itesm.mx</a>
</p>
```

Please help me

Comment: Just looking at the XSL snippet, I think you need to have the `</xsl:if>` after fetching the value. Currently the `<xsl:if>` condition is not performing actual conditional logic.

Comment: Thanks @aniket-v. I tryed this: `<div id="aff-author">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="metadata" select="aff"/>
        <!--xsl:value-of select="content-type[.='original']"/ -->
        <xsl:if test="content-type[.='original']">
        <xsl:value-of select="content-type[.='original']"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </div>`  and the result is the same

Comment: Can you share the complete XML and XSLT? `content-type` is an attribute of `<institution>` and your code does not access `<institution>` nodes. Also attributes have to be accessed using `@` e.g. `@content-type` to fetch their values.

Comment: @NereidaSpiral Are you using CSS at all? If so I can answer with CSS selector (I'm huge on using XML parser but I'm not familiar with XSLT).